# Travelling to Algeria through Barcelona

Tags: uk, schengen, transit-visas, spain, algerian-citizens

I am contacting you guys concerning problems during my trip through Barcelona Airport.

I have booked two separate flight from the UK to Barcelona with Vueling, and then Barcelona to Algeria with Air Algérie from the same airport. I hold an Algerian passport and I'm not required to get a Schengen (airport) transit visa in Spain.
However, since my flights are separate (not connecting) and with two different airlines, I was wondering:

1. Do I need a visa to Spain (transit or short stay) to board my plane from the UK? Since the first flight is not connected to the second, I was concerned that the airline won't allow me to board to Spain without a visa
2. Can I stay in the international transit Area even though the flights are not connected?
3. Can I get my checked luggage in the transit area to check-in again for my next flight? Or should I just take hand luggage

Thank you

Comment: Follow Hilmar's advice in the Answer and put your data into the IATA Travel Center website. I did so (with made-up data for an Algerian citizen living in Algeria). IATA reported that "Flights to Algeria are suspended."

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need a visa to Spain (transit or short stay) to board my plane from the UK?

Most likely yes. Vueling sold you a flight to Spain and they are required to check your eligibility to enter the destination. What happens when you get there is not their concern. If you are lucky there are regulations that exempt you if you stay less than 24 hours and have proof of onward travel. Put your details in https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm and see what you get. You would also need to call Vueling and confirm that they accept your booking.

> Can I stay in the international transit Area even though the flights are not connected?

Unlikely. This depends on the layout of the airport, your specific flight details and the current check-in procedures. For the layout related stuff, check https://www.aeropuertobarcelona-elprat.com/ingl/flight-connections-barcelona.htm

You will need a boarding pass and you apparently can't get for Air Algerie airside in Terminal 1. So  you would have to check in online. Unfortunately check-in procedures during Corona are unpredictable and change frequently. Many international flights don't allow online check-in since the airline has to do a manual documentation check at the check-in counter (passport, visa, corona test, entry forms, vaccination certificates, etc.)

> Can I get my checked luggage in the transit area to check-in again for my next flight?

No

> Or should I just take hand luggage

That would help.

Relying on an airside transfer is very risky and by far the safest route is to plan for full legal entry into Spain and allow at least 4 hours between flight.

Comment: Even more safe, do not travel with separate tickets as long as the flight situation is still to much out of order. If one of the companies decides to cancel the flight, you have your other ticket but will not be able to use it.